# Guardar fecha en un txt PERL

Tags: perl

Necesito guardar información de la fecha con un cierto formato, lo que he hecho es lograr que me imprima el formato que necesito, pero no lo guarda en el archivo de texto, solo lo crea.

```
my $vbbaAnt;
my $hsbcAnt;
my $scotiaAnt;
my $bancomHoy;
my $santanHoy;
```

## Busca la hora de la maquina

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
my @dias = qw( Dom  Lun Mar Mier Jue Vie Sab );
$year += 1900;
$mon++;
```

## Si el mes es menor a 10 le añade un cero al principio

```
if ($mon <  10)
{
    $mon = 0 . $mon;
    print $mday;
}
```

## fecha de actual

```
my $hoy;
$hoy = <"$mday . $mon . $year">;

open ("$mday . $mon . $year", '>> viernes.txt');

print "$dias[$wday]\n";
```

## Muestra la fecha en formato "dd mm aaaa"

```
print "\n$mday-$mon-$year";
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas abrir el archivo con open(), y luego hacer un print() con el identificador que hayas usado en el open(). Finalmente, haces un close() para cerrar el acceso al archivo.

Tienes un ejemplo en 
http://perlenespanol.com/tutoriales/bases_de_datos/base_de_datos_txt_parte_i.html

y en la sección de foros, centenares más.